# Does OmniAuth provide simple hooks to the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I am working on integrating Omniauth with my new Facebook application, and I am looking through the rather sparse documentation to understand if it gives simple ways to access the graph API... I am moving from Koala which was pretty simple.

Has anyone out there used Omniauth for this yet?  I want to get photos from the users' albums, and sort and get the unique URLs for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get fb_graph to work properly - I am still a noob having been a Ruby On Rails developer for a total of about 8-10 weeks, and therefore don't have an instinct for what must be obvious problems to other folks.

However I found this great little blog post which outlines a simple facebook client and shows clearly how it all plugs together.  I found an issue with it picking up the me/picture object as Facebook returns an http302 not http200 but that was easily worked around with the help of the author.  Check it out:  http://bnerd.de/misc/ruby-write-basic-client-for-facebook-graph-api/

I am now using Omniauth for the simplicity of the login/signup interaction based on this walkthrough here: blog.railsrumble.com/blog/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth and with the token I get from that I am using this simple FBClient from the bnerd reference above to access the Graph API.  Hope what I found helps others.

...here's my version of bnerd's code and it worked for me:

```
    class FBClient

      def initialize(app, access_token = nil)
        @app = app
        @access_token = access_token
      end

      # request permission(s) from user
      def request(perms)
        #create a random verifier to identify user on fb callback
        verifier = (0...10).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join
        uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=#{@app.app_id}&redirect_uri=#{@app.connect_url}?verifier=#{verifier}&scope=#{perms}"

        request = { :verifier => verifier, :uri => uri }
        return request

      end

      def connect(code, verifier)

        uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{@app.app_id}&redirect_uri=#{@app.connect_url}?verifier=#{verifier}&client_secret=#{@app.secret}&code=#{CGI::escape(code)}")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true

        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path + "?" + uri.query)
        response = http.request(request)     
        data = response.body

        return data.split("=")[1]
      end

      # get, post
      def get(path, params = nil)
        uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/" + path)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true

        if params.nil?
          params = Hash.new
        end

        if params["access_token"].nil? 
          params["access_token"] = @access_token unless @access_token.nil?
        end

        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path) 
        request.set_form_data( params )
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path + "?" + request.body)

        return response = http.request(request)
      end

      def post(path, params = nil)
        uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/" + path)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true        

        if params.nil?
          params = Hash.new
        end

        if params[:access_token].nil?
          params[:access_token] = @access_token unless @access_token.nil?
        end

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path) 
        request.set_form_data( params )
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path + "?" + request.body)

        response = http.request(request)
        response.code == "200" ? feed = JSON.parse(response.body) : raise("Sorry, an error occured. #{response.body}")
        return feed
      end
    end
```

I am sure someone more experienced than I could improve this - I was about 10 weeks into learning Ruby (and my first programming since Fortran and Pascal at university in the early 90s!).

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me and solved my problem.  Hence the check mark.  Other answers may solve the problem for other people.

Answer (score 14):

I finally found out:

1) include [this gem](http://github.com/nov/fb_graph)

2) use the gem:

`user = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => session[:omniauth]["credentials"]["token"])`

`user.fetch`

3) retrieve your information
`user.name`

Remember you can get anything from here ttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: thanks - i will try this out... i have been trying to work with the code on here:  http://bnerd.de/misc/ruby-write-basic-client-for-facebook-graph-api/ which certainly taught me a lot about the basics

Comment: the problem i get using the bnerd.de code is that Facebook's graph API calls seem to be returning 302 redirect not 200 ok http responses and i am not smart enough to rewrite bnerd's code to accommodate this..  i will attempt to use the FbGraph Gem and if I have better luck than you I'll post an update

Comment: I am getting uninitialized constant error for User::FBGraph - I am trying to call FBGraph from the User model creation function that I have... I added fb_graph to my gemsfile - not sure what else I could do to make sure it's working... any thoughts?

Comment: Well, nothing about your own User model. 'FbGraph::User' is built in the gem.

Comment: oh i get that... i was just adding context for the problem - i am calling FBGraph from within my User model before saving the new user object i want to pull data from the graph... but for some reason i am getting Uninitialized constant User::FBGraph error when i do this though :-(

Comment: ok :) I don't understand why you write User::FBGraph instead of FbGraph::User ;)

Comment: the error message is:  'uninitialized constant User::FBGraph' ...it is being called as an error on the following line in the User.rb file: " user = FBGraph::User.fetch(fbuid, :access_token => token) " ...where fbuid is an already created local variable with the fbuid of the user in it and token is the access token ...clearer?

Comment: User.rb line 20:  user = FBGraph::User.fetch(fbuid, :access_token => token) ## generates an error message 'uninitialized constant User::FBGraph'

Comment: as I wrote above, I first create: user = FbGraph::User.new(fbuid, :access_token => token), then fetch it. But maybe the gem provides this direct method.

Comment: thanks - appreciate your help _ I am doing all of this but for some reason it won't work... meh - I found another solution and i'll post that below

Comment: hmm - didn't mean to downvote this ...sorry - it won't let me know correct that and click on upvote :-(

Comment: @Richard Jordan: I've just edited my answer so that you can change your vote :)

Answer (score 4):

Another good option is Koala: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

If you're just using Facebook, Koala has its own OAuth support. It also works fine with OmniAuth. To use them together, set up OmniAuth per this Railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Then add a 'token' column to 'authentications' table, and any supporting methods for retrieving tokens. When the app needs to interact with Facebook, let Koala grab the token and do its thing. In a controller:

```
if @token = current_user.facebook_token
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token)
  @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
end
```

Comment: i like the idea of combining them like that - my first gem in this journey was Koala until i discovered omniauth ...if i can combine the two this is definitely worth looking at... thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, I would go for fb_graph, just compare:

with **koala**:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

with **fb_graph**:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
my_friends = me.friends
me.feed! :message => "I am writing on my wall!"
```

When using **omniauth**, every user has many authorizations (facebook, twitter, ...)

For each user authorization, you should store the oauth **token** that is returned in your oauth callback hash.

```
auth = Authorization.create!(:user => user,
                             :uid =>      hash['uid'],
                             :provider => hash['provider'],
                             :token =>    hash['credentials']['token'])
```

Then wherever you want to access albums and photos, do something like this:

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :authorizations
  ...
  def grap_facebook_albums
    facebook = authorizations.where(:provider => :facebook).first
    fb_user = ::FbGraph::User.fetch facebook.uid, :access_token => facebook.token
    fb_albums = fb_user.albums
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems getting the devise+Omniauth solution to work. I had to problems:

1. The session cookie did not store the facebook authentication token that is necessary to initialize fb_graph and koala.
2. I was unable to initialize fb_graph after getting the facebook authentication token in place (but got Koala to work after some work).

I solved #1 by inserting 'session[:omniauth] = omniauth' into the create method of the authentications_controller.rb.

I solved #2 by using Koala. Seem like fb_graph requires oauth2, and the devise omniauth integration use oauth. Koala works with perfectly with the facebook authentication token stored by session[:omniauth]["credentials"]["token"].

You initialize koala like this:
 - @fbprofile =
   Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new( 
   session[:omniauth]["credentials"]["token"]
   )

Answer (score 0):

I made sure oauth and oauth2 were uninstalled, and then I installed oauth2.  It appears that now omniauth and fb_graph are working ... but probably need to test it more.